# Can't connect to dockerized tor proxy

Tags: docker, tor, alpine-linux

On Lubuntu I was able to use tor just by installing it and then connecting to its socks proxy, but on docker with alpine it doesn't seem to be that easy.
Since I left my /etc/tor/torrc the way it came, it only consisted of lines that were commented out. So for alpine I just used the `torrc.sample` file which also only had lines that were commented out.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add tor curl && rm /var/cache/apk/* && cp /etc/tor/torrc.sample /etc/tor/torrc 
EXPOSE 9050
USER tor
CMD /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc
```

Then I just ran:

```
$ sudo docker build -t tor .
$ sudo docker run --name tor -p 9050:9050 tor
$ curl -x socks5://localhost:9050 -k https://23.128.64.134/ip
curl: (7) Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response.
$ curl -x socks4://localhost:9050 -k https://23.128.64.134/ip
curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS4 connect request ack.
```

But as you can see I'm not able to connect. Neither via socks4 nor via socks5.

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I've already tried using different ports and host names (127.0.0.1 instead of localhost), but nothing is working.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Interestingly though, this appears to work:

```
$ sudo docker exec -ti tor curl -x socks5://localhost:9050 -k https://23.128.64.134/ip
185.220.101.69
```

(185.220.101.69 is indeed a Tor exit node IP address)

So what could be wrong here? Why can't I access it from the outside? Even `nmap` is reporting that it can see the port (when run outside of the container):

```
9050/tcp open  tor-socks
```

**Edit2:**
I added the `-v`-flag to curl and enabled more verbose logging in tor via `echo "Log info stdout" > /etc/tor/torrc`.

The tor log doesn't change at all when I run the curl command from outside the container. The curl output also doesn't show anything helpful:

```
$ curl -v -x socks5://localhost:9050 -k https://23.128.64.134/ip
*   Trying ::1:9050...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* SOCKS5 communication to 23.128.64.134:443
* Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response.

$ curl -v -x socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -k https://23.128.64.134/ip
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9050...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* SOCKS5 communication to 23.128.64.134:443
* Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response.
```

Comment: The default SOCKSPort for Tor is 9050, not 9150.  Try exposing and connecting to 9050 instead?

Comment: You are right about the port. Unfortunately I still get the same results. Interestingly though, the exact same curl commands work when ran from within the container. So it seems the port mapping is broken in some way.

Comment: Have you tried running the container using a privileged mode? Just for testing…

Comment: I just tried, but the results were the same.

Comment: This is most probably a firewall issue within your system.

Comment: I don't see how this would be a firewall issue. I have no trouble accessing exposed ports of other containers like port 9222. I never had to configure anyhting in my firewall in roder to access those, unless I wanted to access them from another machine on my network, which is not the case here.

Comment: From outside, try `curl -v ...` to see curl debug info, and enable [`Log`](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#Log) option in the tor config and write log to somewhere you can see. Hopefully one of those two might reveal what the problem is. Seems like something up with the docker port forward though.

Comment: Couldn't find anything suspicious. (see edit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The problem is that Tor by default doesn't bind to all interfaces (as in `0.0.0.0`) which doesn't play nicely with Docker.

This can be fixed by adding `SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9050` to the `/etc/tor/torrc`.

So the solution is:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add tor curl && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    cp /etc/tor/torrc.sample /etc/tor/torrc && \
    echo "SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9050" > /etc/tor/torrc
EXPOSE 9050
USER tor
CMD /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc
```

Then everything works as expected:

```
$ sudo docker build -t tor .
$ sudo docker run --name tor -p 9050:9050 tor
$ curl -x socks5://localhost:9050 https://ifconfig.io/ip
190.216.2.136
```

Comment: Not sure why && is used instead of ; , I have seen where && sometimes does not as expected FYI

Comment: Yeah and while were on it, let's pipe stderr into /dev/null so that we never get error messages. There is a huge difference between `;` and `&&`. `&&` is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Eh, seems like a hot mess to me to figure out what went wrong with that oneliner like that but to each is own

Comment: Definitely less time than it would take if you used `;` for no good reason. If you know the basics about Bash it doesn't take more than a few seconds to figure out which command in that one-liner failed.

Comment: @MikeQ - the one-line format is used in dockerfiles to write changes to a single layer of the image. Each 'RUN' command writes a new layer. If you write a file in one layer and remove it in another then it isn't really removed -- it's just hidden in the new layer. This means that when you're doing an install you want to update and install everything in a single line, then tidy up, just to keep the layer tidy, otherwise you can never remove the temporary files and junk from the image.

Comment: @Forivin thanks, this answer really helped. Can you share the link to the docs from where you found out this?

Comment: @aquaman I had to figure that out on my own. There was no doc that I copied this from.